# Array Syntax to populate Flash combobox

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got an array that looks like this, iterating through:

```
(languageArray[i].languageName);  //e.g. "French"
(languageArray[i].languageCode);  //e.g. "fre"
```

I'm trying to populate a fl.controls.ComboBox dataProvider with this array. What I want to do is set the labelfield, as shown in the documentation:

```
myComboBox.dataProvider = dp;
myComboBox.labelField = "firstName";
```

For my code:

```
myComboBox.dataProvider = dp;
myComboBox.labelField = languageName;
myComboBox.data = languageCode;
```

In other words I want the name to be displayed, and the 'data' to be the code, which will be called when I click on the item. But the labelField is not the same as "French". How do I create the two fields in the array such that I can designate the first as labelField and the second as data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jens answered,

```
myComboBox.labelField = "languageName";
myComboBox.dataField = "languageCode";
```

Should correct this. The labelField and data properties are looking for a String to later use to reference the object's property.

Without the quotes, You're telling it to look in the future for an Object's (whatever languageName evaluates to in this context) property. (IE: if languageName evaluates to "Class 0xAB12CB00", or a similar useless toString in this context, it will attempt to find object["Class 0xAB12CB00"] and use that as the labelField).

Comment: myComboBox.labelField = "languageName"; //works great BUT...
myComboBox.data = "languageCode";  //Access of possibly undefined property data through a reference with static type 
 fl.controls:ComboBox.

Comment: @David, Ah. Well, that was my bad, I assumed it was some property I wasn't familiar with. Try 'dataField'

Comment: no problem. Many thanks for your help. The way to access it is in the event:     trace(e.target.selectedItem.languageCode);

Answer (score 2):

```
myComboBox.labelField = "languageName";
```